# MINGW + SQLITE3 - DLL / Linker Issues

Tags: c, sqlite, mingw

Trying to call SQLITE3 functions in MINGW C - program does not behave as expected.  I suspect the issue is around the .a file but cannot see where or why there is no output.

Installed latest MinGW Distro from nuwen.net on Windows 10 in c:\mingw.

```
C:\c>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --with-tune=haswell --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (GCC)
```

Downloaded sqlite-amalgamation-3260000.zip, sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3260000.zip and sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3260000.zip from sqlite.org.

The headers sqlite3.h and sqlite3ext.h were copied from sqlite-amalgamation-3260000.zip to the include\sqlite3 directory.

The files sqlite3.def and sqlite3.dll were extracted from sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3260000.zip to a temporary directory.

In the temporary directory, I ran dlltool -U -d sqlite3.def -l libsqlite3.a  (as described in http://www.mingw.org/wiki/createimportlibraries).
(note I tried with and without -U and -k flags)

No messages were output and the libsqlite3.a file is approx 200K (although I note .DLL is 10x size).  I copied the resultant libsqlite3.a to the lib directory.

I write a quick test3.c program just to check I can call an sqlite function correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3\sqlite3.h"

sqlite3* db;

int main() {

    printf("Start\n");

    sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

    if(db == 0) {
        printf("Could not open database.\n");
    }
    else {
    printf("Database Open \n");
    }
}
```

I compile with no errors using: gcc test3.c -lsqlite3

I run a.exe and see absolutely nothing - not even the "Start" string printed

I comment out just the "sqlite3_open" line and recompile with same command then run again and I see

```
C:\c>a
Start
Could not open database.
```

As behaviour is unexpected when calling an sqlite3 function, and as the .a file is a tenth of the size of the .DLL, I suspect the problem is there - but still cannot see why the "Start" is not output.

Comment: You need to check the return value of `sqlite3_open()`. It still allocates a database handle and sets the db pointer to it on failure, so you can use it with `sqlite3_errmsg()`. See the documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: Many Thanks - but the problem is I cannot get printf to output anything - even an error string from sqlite3_errstr().  Whatever is happening seems to affect the rest of the program, not just the sqlite3_open().  I have also tried adding an sqlite3_close(db) to see if that addresses problem (it doesn't)

Comment: I have narrowed it down even further - just using sqlite3_libversion() - i.e. not trying to actually open anything - also has the same failure.

Comment: When it comes to C or C++ projects that I want to use sqlite in, I just include sqlite3.c in the project instead of mucking around with using a library version. It's nice to be able to rely on a given version, with known features enabled, and it's one less dependency to worry about.

Comment: Yes!  That works without the library and with sqlite3.c.  Thanks.